# Spring JMS Baeldung tutorial code cannot connect to ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging, spring-jms

I have successfully built example code from [this repo](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/messaging-modules/spring-jms). However, when I run this [testing application](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/messaging-modules/spring-jms/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/jms/testing/JmsApplication.java) I get the following error:

```
ERROR | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue-1' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting. I tried it on my work PC and on an EC2 Windows instance to make sure it's not my company firewall or something like that. Result is the same on both machines.

Comment: `>Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:` simply means ActiveMQ is not running on your local machine.

Comment: ActiveMq is supposed to be embedded in the application, as far as I understand. There is this XML that makes me think so: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/messaging-modules/spring-jms/src/main/resources/EmbeddedActiveMQ.xml

I don't believe I should be running ActiveMQ separately.

Comment: Instead of updating the question with the answer you should just add an actual answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: I can't comment why that example uses tcp, it's a bit unusual to use the `tcp://` transport for tests, most people use the `vm://` transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the embedded ActiveMQ broker I needed to run [unit tests](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/messaging-modules/spring-jms/src/test/java/com/baeldung/spring/jms/testing/EmbeddedActiveMqManualTest.java) included with the project.

The unit test included broker initialization:

```java
public static EmbeddedActiveMQBroker embeddedBroker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();
```